# ¿optimizacion del archivo de creacion de session en hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

buenas, actualmente tengo este archivo que me crea la sesion en hibernate.[image: archivo de creacion de sesion en hibernate]

mi pregunta como podria optimizar esto, por que cuando corro la aplicación esta echo con el patron DAO , en cada instancia de la clase que es la creadora de la sesion vuelve a leer el archivo de configuracion.

Answer (score 0):

De esta manera solo llamas a los metodos y no necesitas estar creando la sesion y transaccion a cada rato, en el caso que necesites cerrar la sesión solo llamas 
     `sesion.close();`

```
private void IniciarOperacion() {
    sesion = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    transaccion = sesion.beginTransaction();
}

private void ManejarException(HibernateException e) {
    transaccion.rollback();
    throw new HibernateException("Error en la capa de datos ", e);
}
```